Address Table Lookups not added to VesionnedTransaction message
I have been struggling with ALT for a while now. I'm basiccally creating an ALT with  a couple of account and can read them fine using getAddressLookupTable.
However when i try to run a VersionnedTransaction using compileToV0Message to a custom anchor Program i can see that nothing is included in the adressTableLookups[] array.
Here is  my code:
const lookupTableAccount = await connection.getAddressLookupTable(lookupTableAddress);
if (!lookupTableAccount.value) {
  throw new Error('Failed to fetch lookup table');
}


console.log("ALT fetched with addresses:", lookupTableAccount.value.state.addresses);

// Create a versioned transaction message
const message = new TransactionMessage({
  payerKey: payer.publicKey,
  recentBlockhash: (await connection.getLatestBlockhash("finalized")).blockhash,
  instructions: [
    instruction, // Add the main instruction
  ],
}).compileToV0Message([lookupTableAccount.value]); // Reference the lookup table here
console.log(message)
// Create a versioned transaction
const versionedTx = new VersionedTransaction(message);
console.log(versionedTx)
// Sign the transaction
versionedTx.sign([payer]);

// Send the transaction

try {
  const signature = await connection.sendTransaction(versionedTx);
  await connection.confirmTransaction(signature);
    

And here is the result  of the debug:
VersionedTransaction {
  signatures: [
    Uint8Array(64) [
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 0
    ]
  ],
  message: MessageV0 {
    header: {
      numRequiredSignatures: 1,
      numReadonlySignedAccounts: 0,
      numReadonlyUnsignedAccounts: 9
    },
    staticAccountKeys: [
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(TesBZ3tcyYUX3UexTCfk4uTCG6J6tLwukUxzdmEpJ43)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(ErBrnnPiCPJGbJZrc4UY8dWeA1vvNDDrTHiaoSkoBcAj)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(8SXRVwJwNtbpBQMKPpVoBKqChwKPW3xyEo8SoqRv3jyS)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(DDGeH6pdv7DY8HzooWC7ZhVAnAGC2ujkYGbt4tTHTCBK)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(9X2VEZ7JZhEVWeU9cEE5PYzo5MhkWJ8Lyd9w5de7J6YA)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(6azKDD2Rf88iHBmJtpJDvmWHd7EghR65Ds2V2UwZj4W)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(VQAWcRRUWSMyGGmFeXrLYiLtmnbi1Yh7d8ZNPm5ZvmC)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(DnCd6ufKeMeaetkYDbrSDSPHwds8cYkT6fBrojkdRJ1i)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(GDBgS5n9LRXwnkFQyUYVp1bSVA9hKXg48shmTgwhStP7)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(5mHAyuCKm4ha8SVUUkjmMrEKEgRoXcybspRCMyb5q5GN)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(BqBLgvRhWcc531RNFPXXW64yt5afqaRn9K3d3SYF1eRJ)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(G11FKBRaAkHAKuLCgLM6K6NUc9rTjPAznRCjZifrTQe2)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(GCyAZ4AxCWCkxGaPmox8SUkLb6pCAbmXXVCodNhJYZUd)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(AZQG3ABwssg5RT9bX1UiewsqNMUHEM3kP7Q7N8XSTcZ2)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(CPMDWBwJDtYax9qW7AyRuVC19Cc4L4Vcy4n2BHAbHkCW)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(9zSzfkYy6awexsHvmggeH36pfVUdDGyCcwmjT3AQPBj6)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(7rQ1QFNosMkUCuh7Z7fPbTHvh73b68sQYdirycEzJVuw)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(11111111111111111111111111111111)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s)]]
    ],
    recentBlockhash: 'AJNGXCXEx4BuSxBWjZPi63Ej9bAWbsFdXoVZZ5idgdqR',
    compiledInstructions: [ [Object] ],
    addressTableLookups: []
  }
}


Any idea on what is going on?

Could be that the instruction does not use (does not refer) any address from the lookup table and thus the compile would not have a reason to place the address lookup table into the mix?

Yep correct ! Took me quite long to understand that the compile function  is actually checking  the accountMetas passed to thz instruction
